# Chrome extension interact with website's dataTable from script SRC

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, datatables, onchange, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to upgrade my chrome extension to change the website's Data Table length to 200 instead of 50.

The website's doesn't have the table in it's source, it withdraws it from the 'jquery.dataTables.min.js' file, and that's why I think i'm not able to trigger the value change.

Chrome extension's manifest:

```
"name": "Extension",
  "version": "1.4",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "description": "Extension",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>", "tabs", "activeTab", "storage"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["insertChange.js"],
  "background": {
  "matches": [ "*://*.website.com/Index/*" ],
  "scripts" : [ "thirdParty/jquery.js", "event.js" ],
  "persistent": false
  },
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ "*://*.website.com/search/*" ],
        "css": [ "CopyPaste.css" ],
        "js": [ "thirdParty/jquery.js", "arrive.js", "loadInsertChange.js" ],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

The event.js file is used to open a few website.com/search pages, the page with the required select element, and run the webScript.js for every tab that it has opened, upon clicking on the extension's icon:

event.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openWeb);
searchOnLoad = true;

function openWeb(url) {
    if (searchOnLoad) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url, active: false}, runSearch);
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.create({url, active: false});
    }
}
function runSearch(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'search.js'});
}
```

Website's DOM after loading the data table:

```
<div class="dataTables_length" id="datatable-responsive_length">
    <label>Show 
        <select name="datatable-responsive_length" aria-controls="datatable-responsive" class="">
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
     entries</label>
</div>
```

Maybe I made a typo in those files so far because they are edited, and not the full files, but trust me it works so far.
Now the 'search.js' that runs on every opened 'website.com/search/' page (which has the select box in it), has the following code:

search.js:

```
$(document).arrive('#datatable-responsive_previous.paginate_button.previous', function() {

    //Add more select options, works good
    select = $('#datatable-responsive_length select');
    select.append('<option value="200">200</option>');
    select.append('<option value="300">300</option>');
    select.append('<option value="500">500</option>');

    //Change select HERE
});
```

Every time I try to change the value and trigger the event behind the value (I am trying to change the value to '200' to increase the data table's length to '200'), it's not working. I am able to set the value, and trigger any change function that i'm binding to the elements change on jquery, but the data table's length does not change. Things I've tried:

```
//Settings the append of 200 to selected, and trigger change:
    select.append('<option value="200" selected>200</option>');
    select.change();

//Applying .val() and change:
    select.val(200).change()
    OR
    select.val(200);
    select.change();

//Tried trigger('change'):
    select.val(200).trigger('change');

//Tried declaring the change function:
    select.change(function() {
        alert('Changed');
    });
    select.val(200).change();
    ** This one triggers the alert, which means the change does work, but it's not applying the data table length change.

//Tried adding the dataTable plugin to my contect scripts, but it creates a new data table on the web page and interacting with it.
  I can't use any dataTable function without adding the plugin, and I've tried declaring the pagesLength on data table options,
  and using .page.len() function but I had no luck.

//Tried some solutions on web that includes creating an event to trigger the select
```

All of these solution DOES work when using chrome console inside that web page, but does NOT work when trying to do it through the extension. I was able only to change the value, and trigger changes function that I've made, but not to interact with the existing data table functions. I believe that the problem is only that the website loads the data table from a script tag with external SRC attribute, and that I have to connect my extension with the website's functions, as it does work when sending the calls through chrome's console.

Any help will be appriciated! I've been trying any solution I've found online. Couldn't find how to make chrome extensions interact with websites functions (I did found the opposite of it).

EDIT1: So i've added two new files, insertChange that contains the function, and was added to web accessible resources:

```
function selectChange(element, len) {
    element.val(len).change();
    console.log('changed!');
}
```

and loadInsertChange.js that i've added to the page's content scripts:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('insertChange.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

The manifesst has also changed accordingly (updated at the top)

Comment: Since it works when using chrome console, the solution is to  [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: Added the function, and all the files, and it calls the new function but still doesn't change the data table's length. function selectChange(element, len) {
 element.val(len).change();
 console.log('changed!');
}

Comment: It should work if it works in the console. You can add `debugger` statement in the code inserted in DOM and reload the tab with devtools open, then step through the code and inspect the values etc.

Comment: When opening the webpage I can execute the function like it's built in, but the extension can't access the function. In the manifest I've added the "web_accessible_resources": ["insertChange.js"] (the function itself), and "loadInsertChange.js" in the contect script of the page (the function to add the script tag).  when executing through the search.js (which is a background script that loads when clicking the icon) I receive 'Uncaught ReferenceError: selectChange is not defined'

Comment: If you see the "not defined" error it means the code was inserted too early. Insert it in `window.onload` event listener or maybe even in setTimeout.

Comment: tried document.ready() and setTimeOut, no success.

Comment: I used 5 seconds, but it was long enough to load the elements before it ran and gave the error. I've updated the question with the new files and their code

Comment: The entire code that works in the console should be used in the page context. In other words your content script should only create the script element. Everything else should be performed in the referenced script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved it by adding an event handeler.
First, created 2 new files - insertChange.js and loadInsertChange.js.

insertChange.js:

```
document.addEventListener('selectChange', function (e){
    var data=e.detail;
    console.log("received "+data);
    $('#datatable-responsive_length select').val(data).change();
    //^^ This is my 'select' element. The data is the value I'm going to pass
});
```

Also added insertChange.js to web_accessible_resources in the manifest.

loadInsertChange.js, content script, to add the insertChange to the DOM:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('insertChange.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
console.log('Load Insert Change Loaded');
```

And in my search.js I just triggered the event inside the insertChange that was inserted to the site's DOM:

```
var data= '200'; //My required value to the select element
var evt=document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
evt.initCustomEvent("selectChange", true, true, data);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```